# CakePHP - Checking from which controller and action request came

Tags: cakephp, request

Hi is there any way to check from where the request came in CakePHP ?
I need to check if user has just registered or not.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help. here is a static class that returns either a controller name or action name:

```
    class CustomRouter extends Object
    {
         public static function controller_name() {
                $url_string = Router::url();
                return ( !empty( $url_string ) && is_string( $url_string ) ) ?
                    explode( '/', $url_string )['1'] :
                    null ;
         }

         public static function action_name() {
               $url_string = Router::url();
               return ( !empty( $url_string ) && is_string( $url_string ) ) ?
                    explode( '/', $url_string )['2'] :
                    'index' ;
         }
     }
```